# Prove that the basis of $M$ such that it does not contain any element from $L$ exists, if $L \subset M$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $M$ be finite-dimensional vector space and let $L$ be a proper subspace of $M$ (so $L \ne M$). Prove that there exists a basis of $M$ such that it contains no element from $L$.

I'm not even sure how to start with this. How is this even possible if $L$ is a subspace of $M$?

Comment: What do you mean by $L \leqslant M$? Subspace notation?

Comment: @xbh Sorry, my bad, I meant subspace instead of subset. The '$\le$' is the sign we usually use for subspace but I'm not sure if it's the correct sign on this site.

Comment: This is possible. Consider $M = \Bbb R^2, L = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\colon x=y\}$, then $M $ has a basis $(0,1), (1,0)$ which contains no vectors from $L$.

Comment: I myself am accustomed to write like this, but this seems not a standard notation.

Comment: I changed the ambiguous symbol to words.

Comment: You can simply say that $L$ is a nonempty subset of $M$, which carries additional structure, i.e. must contain the zero vector and it is linear. Subspaces are defined as such, so proper subset is a perfectly fine notation, although it's better to just state $M$ a vector space and $L$ a proper subspace in your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ be a basis of $L$; extend it to a basis $\{x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n\}$ of $M$.

Now define, for $i=1,\dots,k$, $y_i=x_i+x_{k+1}$ and consider
$$
\{y_1,\dots,y_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n\}
$$

Comment: Notice that $x_i + x_{k+1}$ is not in $L$

Answer (score 0):

I present you with yet another example. Consider the line $L$ to be the subspace generated by the element $(1,1,0)$ Now notice that if $M$ is the plane generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, $M$ contains this line, but $L$ and $M$ are not equal.

We can extend our original line by simply adding $(0,1,0)$ and obtain $\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0)\}$, this is a basis for $M$, but now it contains an element of $L$, oops! We can change this basis by the method described by egreg and obtain $\{(1,2,0), (0,1,0)\}$, Notice that this basis does not contain any elements of $L$, but it generates $M$.